# my navigation bar when I include it appears above

Tags: android, xml

my navigation bar when I include it appears above.

[my navigation bar in separate file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CoAU.png)

[my navigation bar where I want to include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4giKH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use `merge` in this case?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">
//Your Bottom view
</merge>
```

Also in your `BottomView` add this `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` so it will stay to the bottom

Comment: I don’t work friend, follow up

Comment: Why do you use that library when you can use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` :D

Comment: Also we would like to see some code, not just a screenshoots... thanks.

Comment: Thank you I work with that bookstore :). com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.Bottomnavigationview

Comment: according to the tutorial I should use that, but I work properly, Thanks.

Comment: Did it work then?

Answer (score 0):

it should be include like below

```
<include 
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 layout="@layout/bottombar">
```